# Ошибка при компиляции программы в intelliJ IDEA - java: invalid flag -release

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Доброго времени суток. Сам я не JAVA-разработчик, но пришлось вникнуть в работу JAVA c SQL-сервером. Установил IntelliJ IDEA, создал проект, всё как надо. Вот код:

```
package test;

import com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb_test";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    public static void main(String[] args){

            try {
                Driver driver = new FabricMySQLDriver();
                DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try(Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD); Statement statement = connection.createStatement() ) {
                System.out.println(connection.isClosed());
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Начинаю компилировать, выскакивает непонятная ошибка

> Error: java: invalid flag -release

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться, в чём дело.

Comment: дело скорее всего в версии идеи, которая не может корректно работать с новой версией Java. Вам нужна такая версия идеи, которая поддерживает Java 9 (если такая есть вообще).

Comment: Тогда, может быть, разумнее подключить к ней 7 версию JAVA?

Answer (score 1):

Старые версии IDEA плохо работают с JDK 9 версии.

Обновитесь до версии IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5